# Jquery UI : Droppable() is not working after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Why my droppable function is not working after scroll ( means When I drag n drop, three or four times after that when I scroll. My droppable event does not work and when I again come to top and drag n drop the element it start's working. )

Is it a bug or a little problem is in my code.

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

  $(".textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 2500
  });
  $( ".editorDesignView" ).droppable({
        accept: '.textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="" style="background: #4073ff; height:200px; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p></div>';
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();

      }
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
#wrapper {width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
.templateWrapper {width: 30%; height: 100%;float:left;overflow-y: scroll;}
.editorBlock {width: 70%; height: 100%;float:left;position: relative;background-color:#f1f1f1}


.editorDesignView {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/8w01v50g/2/)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. It seems to be working correctly